# Building the infrastructure to support a web application

Tags: linux, high-availability, infrastructure

I am building infrastructure to support a web application. I think I have a decent idea of what the infrastructure should look like, here's what I have:

- 2 x 16GB, 4-Core HAProxy servers for load balancing.
- 2 x 16GB, 4-Core servers that run the app (Mojolicious / Hypnotoad)
- 1 x 8GB, 2-core server for dev environment
- 1 x 2GB, 2-core server for git repositories.

There's more to the infrastructure (monitoring, openldap / kerberos, zmq, etc). We are actually not hosting the database, but rather using Orchestrate.io for that, and zeromq locally to handle API calls.

Anyway, my question: What is this field called? I'd like to do more research into exactly how this should be set up, things I may need, etc. I've seen quite a few 'web app architecture diagrams', but not a single one has show the server's specs. I have questions like, "Are 4 8GB servers behind the load balancer better than 2 16GB servers?" A lot of questions of that nature, but I don't even know where to start to begin researching the subject.

Comment: Capacity planning?

Answer (score 0):

check: [ITIL - Capacity Planning](http://wiki.en.it-processmaps.com/index.php/Checklist_Capacity_Plan)

In terms of your specific questions:

> "Are 4 8GB servers behind the load balancer better than 2 16GB
>   servers?"

it really depends on your architecture, design, other services (monitoring, config. mng. logging etc), etc.